# Programmatically Rotate UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I know how to control the autorotation of a UINavigationController, but I would like to programmatically rotate a UINavigationController: the navigation bar, and view stack, to a specified UIInterfaceOrientation value, regardless of the current device orientation.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, setup your application/view controller to use only one specific orientation (that is, block automatic rotations).

Then you can rotate the underlaying view layer (`UIView.layer` of type `CALayer`) using an affine transform.

Comment: I think that would work.  What appears to also be working is rotating the main application window.  Do oyou see any problems with that approach?

Comment: Originally I wanted to add it to the answer (`UIWindow` inherits from `UIView`) but then I realized it's probably not a good idea to tamper  with `UIWindow`. Maybe OS uses window transform for its own purposes.

Comment: That didn't work, after all.
Under your suggestion, will action sheets, alerts, etc. respect the imposed rotation?

Comment: Not automatically. Maybe you could hack it somehow. Alert is in its own window, I think. Action sheets are just views. What you want to do is not supported, so hacking is the only way.

Answer (score -1):

Implement the `- shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in your view controllers insided the UINavigationController, only return YES on your desired orientation. e.g., the  UINavigationController only display on landscape:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

May this helps.

Comment: That works if that condition is in place when the UINavigationController is in place.  An example of what I want to do is have the device in portrait mode with the UINavigationController displaying a view, and when a new UIViewController is pushed onto the stack, cause the UINavigationController to rotate to LandscapeRight orientation, while the device remains in portrait orientation.

Comment: Then you should config the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key in your app's Info.plist, set the orientations you interest.